# How do you pre-render <InnerBlocks.Content> HTML in parent container?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg, gutenberg-blocks

I am trying to create a Gutenberg FAQ block. Current block structure utilizes nested  as so:

```
<FAQContainer> --> Has InnerBlocks that only allow FAQItem
 <FAQItem>
  <FAQQuestion> --> This has a question attribute that I can access with useSelect in the container.
  <InnerBlocks> --> This allows the user to add answer to question.
```

What I want to do is generate FAQ Schema in the main container. I need both questions and answers to do so. I can access the question utilizing useSelect() and getting the question attribute, but I cannot seem to find a way to pre-render the InnerBlocks component to generate the answer HTML. How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly you want to render the content of an InnerBlocks component. In order to do this you use *<InnerBlocks.Content />* in the save function. I would recommend to check out what's written about the InnerBlocks component at wp-gb.com: https://wp-gb.com/innerblocks/